# uitabbaritem changing font size

Tags: ios

I am using the following code to change the font of UITabBaritem inside a subclass of UITabBarController . Its working in iOS 8 whether this code is compatible with iOS 7.

Thank you

```
 [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                                                    } forState:UIControlStateNormal];



[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor]
                                                    } forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you try it on iOS 7?

Comment: Please change fontName "HelveticaNeue-Bold" to any other name like "Courier" , then tell it is work?

Comment: it is not working in iOS 7 for me.Is there any other way to change the attributes of the title of UITabBarItem